# IOS7 how to hide clock (time) on the UIStatusBar

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios7-statusbar

Is there a way to hide clock(time) from UIStatusBar?[StatusBar without clock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qva0a.png)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not possible in the current iOS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with public API. It is possible to fake it, but it is likely you will get banned for modifying a behavior that the user is accustomed to.

If you are feeling adventurous, you can create a `UIWindow` with the size of the clock, set its background to the color of the background, set its level to `UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1` and display it. It will be on top of the status bar, hiding the status bar clock.

Comment: i have a question regarding UIWindowLevelStatusBar and rotation. can you please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976494/ios-8-7-uiwindow-with-uiwindowlevelstatusbar-rotation-issue

Answer (score 0):

Access the UIWindow. You should get it from the AppDelegate. 
Acesss its subviews and find the Status bar. Within the status bar's subviews identify the clock. Then add a solid white subview to the clock using the clock's bounds as frame.

Frankly, I never did that myself but accessed the network indicator, which follows pretty much the same logic just without adding a subview.

I would not remove the clock view element. Alternatively I might try hiding it or assigning alpha=0 or so.

Comment: I tried this approach but the clock is always on top.

Comment: This answer is not correct. The status bar is not housed in the main application window; it sits in a different window, which cannot be accessed normally using public API (e.g. `[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows` does not return this status bar window).

Comment: Well, it is some time ago that I tried it so far as accessing the network status indicator. Unless there was a change in iOS7, it should work. However, Danil sais that the clock will stay ontop.