# iOS 8 / 7 UIWindow with UIWindowLevelStatusBar Rotation issue

Tags: ios, uiwindow

I'm trying to add a UIWindow with `UIWindowLevelStatusBar` level. it works in portrait mode on ipad perfectly but after rotating device its messed up.

on iOS 7.x all rotations are fine except for upside-down, and on iOS 8.x only portrait mode is fine and all other orientations are messed up. any idea how to solve that?

```
CGRect frame = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame;
self.statusWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, 20)];

UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
CGRect frame = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame;
CGAffineTransform test = [self transformForOrientation:orientation];

[self.statusWindow setWindowLevel:UIWindowLevelStatusBar];
[self.statusWindow setHidden:NO];


- (CGAffineTransform)transformForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
 switch (orientation)
 {
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        return CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90.0f));

    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        return CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90.0f));

    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        return CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(180.0f));

    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
    default:
        return CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(0.0f));
}
}
```

Comment: this is highly random way to handle orientation-support. you should not even think on transforming anything at all because the `UIWindow` can and will handle everything for you as long as you set the `rootViewController` property up correctly.

Comment: Something is missing here in your code, show all the code related to your statusWindow.

Comment: for clarification this code will set another uiwindow over status bar. so there is no rootviewcontroller. if i don't transform the uiwindow stays in portrait mode and won't rotate neither on iOS 7 nor on iOS 8 so one has to rotate manually. if you know better way please share.

Answer (score 0):

In your UIWindow subclass' init method, observe this notification:

```
// Rotation Notifications
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didChangeOrientation:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

self.baseT = self.transform;
```

Then the method itself:

```
- (void)didChangeOrientation:(NSNotification *)n
{

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

    switch (orientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.baseT, 0);
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.baseT, M_PI);
            break;
//      Home button on left
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.baseT, -M_PI_2);
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.baseT, M_PI_2);
            break;
        default:
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
            break;
    }
}
```

Depending on your implementation, you may have to also ensure the frame doesn't change. Also, in the Class' dealloc method, stop listening to the notifications.

Comment: the rotation does work but the uiwindow is not correctly positioned and resized according to screen orientation. thanks for the effort anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As a modification to @dezinezync's answer: performing the rotation would work better if you put it in the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method of the view controller. This way, the rotation will only be applied if the device is rotated to one of the supported orientations specified in the General -> Deployment Info section of the app's build settings. As an added bonus, you get access to the duration of the rotation animation. Just make sure you have a reference to your modal window in the view controller.

The `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` notification is fired whenever the screen orientation changes, regardless of what orientations are supported. This can lead to undesireable behavior.

Here's an example:

```
UIWindow *modalWindow;

// Initialize your modal window somewhere in your code
// ...

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

    // Make sure the modalWindow exists
    if (modalWindow != nil)
    {
        // Animate the modal window's rotation
        [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
            [self rotateModal:modalWindow];
        }];
    }
}

- (void)rotateModal:(UIWindow*)window
{

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

    switch (orientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            window.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.baseT, 0);
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            window.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.baseT, M_PI);
            break;
//      Home button on left
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            window.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.baseT, -M_PI_2);
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            window.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.baseT, M_PI_2);
            break;
        default:
            window.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
            break;
    }
}
```

I just did something like this on a landscape-only app, and I finally got it working properly by moving everything to the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for iOS8 (need a transform as showed above as well):

```
UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
CGRect statusBarFrame = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame;
if ([screen respondsToSelector:@selector(fixedCoordinateSpace)])
{
    [self setFrame:[screen.coordinateSpace convertRect:statusBarFrame toCoordinateSpace:screen.fixedCoordinateSpace]];
}
```

However it does not work for iOS9 beta.